# What error code does a process that segfaults return?

Tags: c, linux, unix, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

What error code does a process that segfaults return? From my experiments, it seems to be "139", but I'd like to find why this is so and how standard it is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The relevant syscall (giving the status of a terminated process) is [waitpid(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/waitpid.2.html). The 139 is for `WIFSIGNALED` and `WTERMSIG` etc... On Linux the actual bits are described in internal file `/usr/include/bits/waitstatus.h` which is included from `<sys/wait.h>` header

The `wait`, `waitpid` call is [standard in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html) and so are the macro names (like `WTERMSIG` etc...). The actual implementation of these macros, and the actual signal numbers, hence the code given by the shell, are implementation specific.

The [signal(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html) Linux man page gives the number of the signals.

Answer (score 27):

When a process is terminated, the shell only stores an 8-bit return code, but sets the high bit if the process was abnormally terminated. But because your process is terminated by a segmentation fault, usually the signal that is sent is SIGSEGV(Invalid memory reference) which has a value of 11.

So because your process was terminated abnormally, you have a 128 and then you add the value of the signal that terminated the process which was 11, you get 139.